# Calling a method inside using block

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I've a class `SomeDisposable` and I'm using it in using block like this

```
using(var someDisposable = new SomeDisposable(1)) 
{

}
```

Can I change to something like

```
using (var someDisposable = Get(1))
{

}
public SomeDisposable Get(int x)
{
   return new SomeDisposable(x);
}
```

Would it impact the auto disposable ability?

Comment: That's fine: there are plenty of places in the runtime which do this. `Get` is transferring ownership of `SomeDisposable` to its caller, and it is the caller's responsibility to dispose it

Comment: More detail in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3039218/43846

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler will turn your first code into

```
SomeDisposable someDisposable = new SomeDisposable(1);
try
{
}
finally
{
    if (someDisposable != null)
    {
        ((IDisposable)someDisposable).Dispose();
    }
}
```

It will turn the second code into

```
SomeDisposable someDisposable2 = Get(1);
try
{
}
finally
{
    if (someDisposable2 != null)
    {
       ((IDisposable)someDisposable2).Dispose();
    }
}
public SomeDisposable Get(int x)
{
   return new SomeDisposable(x);
}
```

([Source](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6AsgBQCUhxBSxLmADNQG4CGATugGcA9gFsApgBEAlgIAOQgdwBGAGzHoAvOgB2YgO7oAyqMkz5i1WOpxatdA1b5kD1gF8XLD8Sht0XPoIm0nIKymqa6ADiYgAu1rZeREyJ6O7MxGme6URoRkFmoZZRsdRS2jHoAB702U613gDsOvp54sHmYVbVANwuacj9KKQwraYhFuEg6ACS7YVqyEy5xm0FE1ZlFVI1TIO55OhzAlY7AwNAA===))
As you can see, it doesn't make a difference. The finally block will be executed the very same way in both variants.

Answer (score 2):

No, it would not impact the auto disposable ability. A `using` block will call `Dispose` on the wrapped object at the end of the block, regardless of whether that object was created using the `new X(...)` syntax or was returned from another method.

Comment: @canton7 Care to explain what you mean? The question asks whether a `using` block will work for an object created by a method, rather than an object created inline. What have I misread?

Comment: The answer to the question "Can I change to something like" is Yes. The answer to "Would it impact the auto disposable ability?" is No. The problem is, the question contains both questions and it's unclear which your "No", as the first word of your answer, is in response to.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for pointing that out. Looks like Cleptus has already fixed my answer to clarify that. :)

Comment: Ah yes, I read the "No" as a response to "Can I change to something like"

Answer (score 1):

Both code fragments will behave the same, you're just fiddling with some object references but this won't change the scope of the using statement in this case.