# Disposing of a collection of IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I have a method that returns a collection of DirectoryEntry objects.

```
static IEnumerable<DirectoryEntry> Bar(){ ... }
```

I've been iterating through the collection when I'm finished with it and disposing of each item, but I'm wondering what the best practice is.

Ex.

```
var foo = Bar();
\\ Do some work
foreach (var f in foo)
{
    f.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost.  You should take responsibility to Dispose() disposable objects returned from functions, see eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039196/method-returns-an-idisposable-should-i-dispose-of-the-result-even-if-its-not), probably in a `finally` block.

There's no guarantee that you get the same set of DirectoryEntry object every time you enumerate the IEnumerable (ie with `foo.GetEnumerator()` or `foreach`).  You could get new ones every time, and re-enumerating could cause unnecessarary IO. eg this

```
    static int n = 0;
    static IEnumerable<int> Bar()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            yield return n++;
        }

    }

    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = Bar();
        
        var count = foo.Count();
        foreach(var i in foo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        foreach (var i in foo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

    }
```

will iterate the IEnumrable three times, generating 30 different `int`s.

For this reason, you often need to collect an IEnumerable in a List or other ICollection.

```
var foo = Bar().ToList();
try
{
    // Do some work
}
finally
{
    foreach (var f in foo)
    {
        f.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Something like this

```
foreach (var f in Bar())
{
    using (f)
    {
        //Do some work
    }
}
```

is risky because if `Bar()` returns a collection, and you have an exception, the un-enumerated objects won't get disposed.

Comment: This - using `finally` is the best practice.

Comment: Perfect! In practice, I do have the foreach loop inside of a finally block. I do see why it was important to place that in the post. Thank you.